# How to use a submit button for a form on another page in html

Tags: html, forms

I'm using free version of basin as backend for my form and after submission it redirects to basin's page, but I want to redirect to an invoice page.
So I want to create the submit button on the invoice page.

**Form.html**

```
<form id="myform" action="https://usebasin.com/code" method="POST">
    <input name="name" />
    <input name="email" />
    <input name="number" />

    <a href="invoice.html">Proceed</a>
</form>
```

**Invoice.html**

```
<p>Invoice details</p>
<button for="myform"  type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way a form is suppossed to work.
Read this article on html forms:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```html
<form id="myform" action="YOUR_ADDRESS/invoice.html" method="POST">
    <input name="name" />
    <input name="email" />
    <input name="number" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

This way you send all the parameters to the invoice.html file.

Answer (score 0):

A submit button in HTML always refers to the form it appears in. Thus you cannot submit a form with a button that is placed somewhere else on the page or even on a distinct page using HTML alone.

`<a href="invoice.html">Proceed</a>` on the other hand only loads a new page without submitting the form data. And after you have loaded the second page (invoice.html) that way, the form data from the first page is lost. (Unless invoice.html was opened in another tab, that way you could probably fetch the form data from the first tab using JavaScript.)

If you need to split a form across multiple pages, you can either sent each step individually to the server or store the form data in the local or session storage and sent the data to the server using JS on the last step/page.

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` element can have a `form` attribute that will match the `id` of a `<form>`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

```
<form id="some-id">
...inputs
</form>

<button form="some-id" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

They will both have to be on the same page.